# Automating the creation of a list of lists - Python

Tags: python

I have to create a list of lists that is summarized below:

```
list_of_lists = [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3]....[0,N]]
```

Basically just need the first element of each sub-list to be 0, and the second element to be 1 more than the prior value of the second element.

The value for N is about 2000, so obviously I do not want to type out the whole thing. Is there a simple way to automate with Python?

Thank You

Comment: Have you made any attempt at achieving this programmatically? Python is, after all, a programming language, not a text editor - automation is the main goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simple list comprehension with [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
>>> N = 5
>>> [[0, i] for i in range(1, N + 1)]
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5]]
```

Comment: I just wanted to add this one as well. I have been getting more and more into functional programming.

`list(map(lambda x: [0, x + 1], range(1, N + 1)))`